# C++ std List initialization with a constant value, does it change the performance?

Tags: c++

I am working on a simulator (Computer architecture). 
A piece of code read

```
List freeList;
const int numEntries
registers = new MSHR[numEntries];
for (int i = 0; i < numEntries; ++i) {
    registers[i].queue = this;
    freeList.push_back(&registers[i]);
}
```

I changed it to

```
List freeList;
int numEntries;
registers = new MSHR[numEntries + 100];
for (int i = 0; i < numEntries + 100; ++i) {
    registers[i].queue = this;
    freeList.push_back(&registers[i]);
}
```

Just changing the const numEntries has had a drastic effect on the memory usage. If I run the program for long (Code does a lot of push_back, pop_front on the list), I run into this error

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc

What can be the difference?

Comment: The code as written would not compile, since the semicolon is missing after `int numEntries`.

Comment: I don't see any semantic difference between the two, except the second  allocates more entries. And there's no `std::List` - it's `std::list`.  Are you really using the standard container?

Comment: Yes I am using the std::List and it was just part of the code I copied. numEntries is initialized elsewhere. I was wondering if allocating memory by const size makes a difference?

Comment: It shouldn't, unless that value changes at some point, but the second piece of code allocates 100 more than the original code did.

Comment: Does the 1st piece of code won't get that error if run for long? if yes, it's out of memory allocation.

Comment: Why do you post code with new errors that you claim are not in your original code?

Answer (score 2):

LMGTFY: The [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/bad_alloc/) says "Exception thrown on failure allocating memory".

You are trying to create more objects than you have memory for.

Since `numEntries` is not initialized, that is the problem.

Comment: numEntries is initialized elsewhere in the code. This is only a piece of the code.

Comment: And what is it's value when this code runs?

Comment: +1 because it deals with an obvious error in the code as it was presented.